# Setup of RAID using two 320gb hard disks in a NAS (DNS 323)

Tags: raid-1

Hi there I would like to setup a RAID back up type system where 1 drive is mirroring the other but I want to put them in a NAS so I dont have to fiddle around with the existing hard drives

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

RAID is **not** a backup solution.  RAID protects you from disk failure, nothing more.

The question is what do you want - a backup solution, or protection from disk failure?  If it is to protect from disk failure then see page 15 of [the manual](http://www.dlink.com/products/default.aspx?pid=DNS-323&tab=3) - select `RAID 1`.